# com.mysql.jdbc.Driver not found in Worklight platform or project error

Tags: mysql, jdbc, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, worklight-studio

Worklight Studio v6.2
Eclipse 4.4.0
jdbc driver 5.1.33
MySQL Community Server 5.6.21

I follow the steps below.

SQL adapter – Communicating with SQL database
http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v620/04_03_SQL_adapter_-_Communicating_with_SQL_database.pdf

I imported sample project, and added mysql jdbc driver(mysql-connector-java-5.1.33-bin.jar) under the (Project folder)/server/lib.
After that,I deployed the adapter and invoked it. I got following error.

```
{
   "errors": [
      "Runtime: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver not found in Worklight platform or project \/Adapters"
   ],
   "info": [
   ],
   "isSuccessful": false,
   "warnings": [
   ]
}
```

I guess jdbc driver isn't deployed for worklight development server. But I don't know how.

Comment: Try to restart the worklight server and let me know if it changed anything.

Comment: It doesn't change anything.But it seems that my project is something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I re-created project, adapter and add jdbc conncetor, and deployed adapater. Now it works fine. Thanks.